Game: I can't get 2 whiles loops to work simultaniously
I'm encountering a problem while creating a game. Idea: "Create a game where a zombie approach you, and you need to solve a number of math problems before the zombie reaches you".
The number of questions is 5 and game is over when zombie hand pass x=200, which is coordinate of "the Rock" hand.
I tried different ways to apply a loop that makes the zombie approach the Rock while the user simultaneously answering questions. And when the user answered 5 questions or the zombie reaches you, math questions are taken back and it'll tell you if you win or lose.
I appreciate your help
# Function to check if the input is a natural number
def isNaturalNumber(input_str):
    try:
        number = int(input_str)
        return number > 0
    except ValueError:
        return False
# Function to generate and check users' answer
def generate_question():
    num1 = random.randint(1, 9)
    num2 = random.randint(1, 9)
    correct_answer = num1 + num2

    # Display math problem
    problem_text = Text(Point(400, 250), f"What is {num1} + {num2}?")
    problem_text.setSize(20)
    problem_text.draw(w)

    # Get user's answer
    entry_box = Entry(Point(400, 300), 5)
    entry_box.setSize(20)
    entry_box.draw(w)
    
    while True:
        key = w.checkKey()
        if key == "Return":
            break

    # Checking answer
    answer = entry_box.getText()
    if isNaturalNumber(answer):
        if int(answer) == correct_answer:
            global zombie_health
            zombie_health -= 1  # Decrease the zombie's health
            zombie_health_text.setText(str(zombie_health))  # Update the health display

    # Clear the math problem and user's answer
    problem_text.undraw()
    entry_box.undraw()
    


TheRock_parts = [TheRock_body, TheRock_head, TheRock_eye1, TheRock_eye2, TheRock_gun, TheRock_gun1, TheRock_hand2, TheRock_hand1, TheRock_leg1, TheRock_leg2]



zombie_parts = [zombie_body, zombie_head, zombie_eye1, zombie_eye2, zombie_hand1, zombie_hand2, zombie_leg1, zombie_leg2, zombie_health_text]



while :
    for part in zombie_parts:
        part.move(-0.5, 0)

    
start_game = Text(Point(400, 100), "Please press 'S' to start the game")
start_game.setSize(25)
start_game.draw(w)

# Wait for the user to press 'S'
while True:
    key = w.checkKey()
    if key == "s":
        start_game.undraw()  # Remove the start message
        break  # Exit the loop once 'S' is pressed
        

zombie_hand1_left = zombie_hand1.getP1().getX()

# Movement and question loop
k = ""
while zombie_hand1_left >= 200:
       
    try: 
        generate_question()

    except zombie_health <= 0:
        you_win = Text(Point(400, 300), "You Win! The zombie is defeated!")
        you_win.setSize(20)
        you_win.draw(w)
        break
    except zombie_hand1_left >= 200:
        game_over = Text(Point(400, 300), "Game Over! The zombie reached you!")
        game_over.setSize(20)
        game_over.draw(w)
        break

# Wait for user to close the window

w.getMouse()
w.close()


I understand the difficult part is to keep looping both
for part in zombie_parts:
    part.move(-0.5, 0)

and
generate_question()

at the same time, I tried putting both in a while loop but it didnt work either. And I can't find a tutorial to keep 2 loops running simultaneously

put everyhing under same while cycle, then check every condition only once (no nested "while true"), that way you would be able to update game state step-by-step. BTW, python has concurency, but I don't think it's needed in this case (https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrency.html)

try...except in python is to catch errors known as Exceptions.
The statements after the except are executed after you encounter an error and they must inherit from the BaseException class. They are not for evaluating boolean expressions. For those you need a if or while.

As Benas already said try move everything into one while loop. So that it is updated sequentially, e.g. while True: key = w.checkKey(), if key == s: break elif key == correct_key: ... else: advance zombie

@Daraan and Benas  thanks for the response, but I still cant find way to make 2 loops work simultaneously. I dont think it's possible now that I think about it

Hi, @Benjamin_Do, thanks for the good question! Multiple while loops are indeed possible, using the threading module or the multiprocessing module or asyncio.

In Python, it's not possible to perform simultaneous loops because it's a single-threaded language. I recommend changing your approach for your code and using a single loop that will update the states of your game and check for user inputs.

yeah, i think you're right, i came with a different approach instead, thanks
